# Excel index match, lookup value if date matches or week number of that date matches?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am using the following index match array formula on my home sheet:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Data!B:B,MATCH(1,(Home!H10=Data!C:C)*(Home!I10=Data!D:D)*(Home!J10=Data!E:E),0)),"")
```

This looks up my PO number from column B, on data sheet, where the values on home sheet match.

```
Data: 
Column B         Column C      Column D     Column E         COlumn F (Week number)
12345678910      123           5555         21/12/2016       51

Home: 
Column H      Column I     Column J         Column K         Column J
123           5555         21/12/2016                        12345678910
```

This gives the PO in column J as a result. This works fine.

Here's my problem:

I want the user to be able to enter either a specific date, i.e. 21/12/2016 in column E and have this find a match. But, sometimes, the user will not know the specific date, and will only have a week number.

Therefore, if the user enters in the week number for 21/12/2016, then my index match formula should still find a match regardless.

The second problem i'm having is unless i format column J on home sheet as date, then my date does not format properly and i get '42725'.

So this has to be set as date in order for the index match to find a result.

But then if the user wants to enter the week number in column J (with a date format), i.e. 51 - then it displays '20/02/1900'. And likewise, my index match will not return a result.

Comment: This looks like an excel formula question, not a VBA question.

Comment: @C8H10N4O2 yes sorry thanks missed that

Comment: @ScottCraner thanks i've tried that but this doesn't solve my issue around the formatting in column J. If i type in a week number into a date formatted cell it doesn't display as a week number. Is there a format workaround i could use for this column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instaed of `..*(Home!J10=Data!E:E)...`

Use this in its place:

```
.....*(IF(Home!J10<55,Home!J10,WEEKNUM(Home!J10))=Data!F:F)...
```

Leave the column Formatted as General and each cell will then change to a date if a date is entered and a number if a week number is entered.

You may need to go through and reenter some of the entries to get them back to what they should be the first time, but any new entries will shift on their own.

Comment: @Princess.Bell so did my answer to your question yesterday work for you?

Comment: not exactly no, and whilst this formula does seem to be working, i think theres an issue with the data on my data sheet. Since i am using formulas to get my values and for some reason it doesn't seem to find them unless i type them in as values

Comment: it also seems to be failing to get a result with the more rows of data i have in sheet 'data'. I have about 5000 rows of data at the moment which is not giving me any results

Comment: also oddly, despite me knowing that certain rows definitely match, it fails to find them and if I manually try to ctrl + f the values in each of the columns as well - excel still fails to find them. I am using left mid and right formulas to get my values on sheet 'data'. Don't know if that is what's preventing them. I don't think it is though since if I reduce my rows of data it does find them.

Comment: It is trying to do too many caculations.  As I explained you need to limit the full column references to only those that have data.  You are doing over 8 million calculations per formula.  5000 rows means that it is doing over 5 trillion calculations.  At about 7 million per second it is going to take over 12 minutes just to do those 5000.  As per the left and right.  They output strings and will not match to numbers.

Comment: This would be a lot easier in a database using sql queries.  You may want to consider using Access instead.

Comment: If I limit my rows of data is there a way I could make the left and right formulas produce a number rather than a string or reference the string as a number in order to get a matching result?

Comment: put `--` in front of them. ***warning this will create an error if what is returned cannot be changed to a number.***

Comment: as in =Left(- -A1,4) ?

Comment: No, in front `=--LEFT(A1,4)`

Comment: would my date, which I am also getting by using a formula, also be a string? And how can I prevent this if needs be? Or does the date not matter if it's a string?

Comment: It depends, is the data you are trying to match a string or a true date.  IF both are true dates, they can be modified by changing the format of the cell, then it does not matter what they look like.  IF you use TEXT() to set the date or it does not change when reformatting the cell then both have to be a string and look exactly the same.   I have to go, so if you have future questions like this SuperUser.com is where you would ask them, as they do not specifically relate to problematic code.